# How would I create a Workflow?

Tags: sharepoint-server, workflow, sharepoint-foundation

I have two library(Current and Review Library) in one site collection and one archive library in another site collection.

Requirements:

The system will immidiatlly remove the document from the current document grid and place it into a queue for Document review.The fololowing required will happen. 
If:

```
     A- Duplicate document
     B- Document Name incorrectly
     C- Incorrect workspace
     D- Others(If others is selected , then comment field is required)
```

Note: Remove means to move a document from the current document grid to the drop-off library.

Comment: Please expand on your question, I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: The above requirements, A or B or C happened, The item remove from the current to archive. Make sure that the archive lives on different site collection.